# Pandas Version 12 - add new 'column' to series

Tags: python, pandas, series

In Pandas ver 0.12, how do I add a new field to a `Series`?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
'0.12.0'
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                        'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                    'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                        'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                                'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                        'texture': ['soft', 'soft', 'hard','soft','hard',
                                            'hard','hard','hard'],
                        'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                            'triangular','round','triangular'],
                        'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'texture', 'shape', 'amount'])

    b = df.iloc[1]
    type(b)
    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The below syntax works for Pandas ver 13 and higher, but fails for ver 12:

```
b['new_col'] = 123
error: 'new_col not in this series!'
```

Similary, the below works for ver>= 13 but again fails in version 12:

```
b.loc['new_col'] = 123
error: 'new_col'
```

Finally I tried this, it does not give an error but does not add the new field - value pair either:

```
b.set_value('new_col', 123)
```

How can I add this new column to the series `b` in Pandas version 12?

Comment: Can you upgrade? Because you really, really, really should upgrade if you can. And if you can't, then you should contact whoever you need to contract to get them to upgrade. There have been **a lot of bug fixes** between 0.12 and 0.15.

Comment: @Ffisegydd tell me about it... For various reasons I can't upgrade. Having to deal with ver 12 is becoming the bane of my life.

Comment: Does it work if you add the column to the df first and then take the slice?

Comment: @EdChum, yes it does. It's just I cannot add a new 'col' to a `Series`.

Comment: Well your first line `b['new col'] = 123` raises a SettingWithCopyWarning warning in pandas 0.15.2. Could you try `b = df.iloc[1].copy() b['new col'] = 123` I don't know if that will work to be honest

Comment: @ EdChum, I know - I think the correct way to write that in ver>12 is `b.loc[:, 'new_col']`. Version 12 does not like this either.

Comment: Using append is something that will work for both cases I think: `b.append(pd.Series({'new_col':123}))`. But, in any case, maybe you should also think about if this is necessary: adding an entry into a row (which is a series) of a dataframe seems not very efficient.

Comment: Furthermore, `set_value` does work, it only creates a new object, so you have to assign it: `b = b.set_value('new_col', 123)`